# Personal Dictionaries

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, swype, dictionary

I use swype beta on my galaxy nexus (ICS). When I type some word that is not in the dictionary, swype prompts me to add the word to its "personal dictionary". However, even after I go along with that, the word does not get added to the system's underlying personal dictionary and so I get a spelling error indication which prompts me to add the word to the system's "personal dictionary".

Is there a way of avoiding this two-step process. Is there a way of configuring swype to use the underlying personal dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
Swype, just like other similar keyboard apps use their own dictionaries. The spelling correction, and the underlying dictionary that you're referring to was added in 4.0 and none of the 3rd party keyboards apps integrate with it just yet.

At this point we need to wait.